# How to get simulation warning when comparing std_logic with 'X'?

Tags: vhdl

In order to catch more bugs in simulation, it is an advantage to get a warning
if `std_logic` with `'X'` is used in `=` compare.

When using the `ieee.std_logic_1164` package, the `std_logic` compare function
`=` does not warn about `'X'` in either of the operands.  So the ´if´ branch in
the code below is taken when `sl_i` is `'1'`, but the `else` branch is taken
when `sl_i` is either of `'0'`, `'X'`, etc.:

```
if sl_i = '1' then
  sl_o <= '1';
else  -- sl_i in "UX0ZWLH-"
  sl_o <= '0';
end if;
```

So for example an `'X'` or `'U'`, due to use of some unknown or uninitialized
value, is silently ignored during simulation.  However, if a warning was given,
it would improve the possibility of finding bugs in simulation, like when the
`ieee.numeric_std` package warns about metavalue (`'X'` etc.) in compare with
`=`.

? Is there any standard VHDL way to get warning for metavalues in `std_logic`
at compare with `=` ?

One possibility, is to make a package where the implicit `=` for `std_logic` is
redefined, and then use this package with `.all` so the `=` is replaced.  Such
package with may look like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic;

package std_logic_warning is
  function "="(l, r : std_logic) return boolean;
end package;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.is_x;
use ieee.std_logic_1164;  -- For access to "=" using std_logic_1164."="

package body std_logic_warning is

  function "="(l, r : std_logic) return boolean is
  begin
    assert not (is_x(l) or is_x(r))
      report "std_logic_warning.""="": metavalue detected"
      severity WARNING;
    return std_logic_1164."="(l, r);
  end function;

end package body;
```

? Will such a redefine be VHDL standard compliant, and is it likely to work
with the tools in general ?

As Jim Lewis points out with reference to [ISAC
IR2058](http://www.eda.org/isac/IRs-VHDL-2002/IR2058.txt) the idea of
overriding the implicit `=` may not work in general for tool when using
VHDL-2003.  VHDL-2008 should fix this.

---

Note that above question and suggestion has been edited based on David Koontz
previous comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which language revision you are using, you may experience portability problems.  I suggest you avoid them by using VHDL-2008, which removes a number of issues.

Prior to VHDL-2008, some tools did not allow explicit operators to overload implicit operators.  Prior to VHDL-2008, tools interpreted the reference to "ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic" differently.  See ISAC IR2058 for a discussion:  http://www.eda.org/isac/IRs-VHDL-2002/IR2058.txt.  Even with the implementation of IR2058, my interpretation is that is_x will not be included in your reference to std_logic as only overloaded operators are included and not all functions - so if that works it is probably not portable between tools.

Hence, I would use VHDL-2008 and the following code.  I replaced the reference to ieee.std_logic_1164."=" with one to ieee.numeric_std.std_match, as it is not clear to me if you can still reference an implicit operator once an explicit operator is visible to replace it - even if it is legal, I would expect this to be a fringe case that may break tools (make sure to report the bugs).   Use of std_match also has the benefit of correctly handling an 'L' or 'H'.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package std_logic_warning is
  function "="(l, r : std_logic) return boolean;
end package;

package body std_logic_warning is

  function "="(l, r : std_logic) return boolean is
  begin
    assert not (is_x(l) or is_x(r))
      report "std_logic_warning.""="": metavalue detected"
      severity WARNING;
    return ieee.numeric_std.std_match(l, r);
  end function;

end package body;
```

If you don't like the behavior of std_match, you can use std_match as a template to create the functionality, however, I don't recommend this as synthesis tools may not like it.

While you could use the modified "=", as a counter suggestion, there are two sources of X, external from other designs and internal from uninitialized registers.  I don't worry about uninitialized registers as I am rigorous about my resets.  Hence, at the core level, I may (depending on my confidence of others or the testbench), use the assert statement directly on core inputs.

```
assert not is_x(core_input_1) 
  report "meta value detected on core_input_1" severity ERROR ;
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful.  The `std_match` would be a good replacement, but are you saying that synthesis tools may not support it ?  Otherwise, access to the original `std_logic` operators can be made through an extra package `'std_logic_original'`.  Applying explicit `'X'` checking with extra code may be pretty cumbersome for external protocols and internal RAMs.  The thought is that the `use.std_logic_warning.all` may be added to already written code, for a quick way to add `'X'` checking.  I assume it would improve simulation test quality if the VHDL language supported something like this.

Comment: std_match should be well supported by synthesis tools.  

My concern was replacing it with behavior you write.  Not as sure about "=" behavior, but if you replace something like rising_edge(Clk) or "+" with the code that is actually in the corresponding package, there is no guarantee that it will produce your desired results.  That is because the stuff in std_logic_1164 and numeric_std are not synthesized, but rather the packages are known packages with known behavior.  Some tools use pragmas (comments with meaning) and attributes to direct the synthesis tool to the implementation of these.

Comment: Curiously, the language already does this for "=" with type ieee.numeric_std.unsigned.  Hence, if you use numeric_std_unsigned, for std_logic_vector, it is already supported.  There is just no similar overloading for std_ulogic.

Comment: The implicit "=" for std_logic in the language cannot change since there are things that need to test for 'X'.  Not sure there would be an appropriate place to overload the implicit behavior.  I also looked at the behavior for ?= and it does pass "X" through correctly, however, "??" does not check for meta values, which perhaps it should produce a warning.

Comment: In test bench code I see that `=` must be able to compare with `'X'` without a warning.  For design (synthesizable) modules I assume that a `'X'` in `=` compare does most likely indicate something the designer want to look further into, and maybe qualify with some guard expression, with benefit of VHDL short circuit evaluation.

Comment: Ok, given that testbench code and rtl code have different requirements, how do you propose to address it?  My thought is to use VHDL-2008 "?=" for RTL and explore revising "??" so that it flags an error.

Comment: It is probably OK to use the `=` without warning generation in test bench code, since this is for simulation only, and simulation is generally based on using the full `std_logic` value range, where modules for HW is designed thinking in 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for the template using `std_match`, but based on David Koontz comment I lean to not changing the actual compare operation of `=`, but simply generating a warning.

Comment: See your point about `??` for VHDL-2008, and would be great if that generated a warning for metavalues, instead of just doing the boolean conversion secretly.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things wrong with this scenario.

There isn't an explicit `std_logic_1164."="` defined. Equality and inequality operators are implicitly declared for all types.

IEEE Std 1076-1993 Section 3  Types, Para 2:

> ...The set of operations of a type includes the explicitly declared
>   subprograms that have a parameter or result of the type. The remaining
>   operations of a type are the basic operations and the predefined
>   operators (see 7.2). These operations are each implicitly declared for
>   a given type declaration immediately after the type declaration and
>   before the next explicit declaration, if any.

The extended name should be `ieee.std_logic_1164."="`.

A relational operator in an expression is given as an operator symbol, so no extended name with left and right arguments.  A function call to the equality operator function you've declared can be an extended name.

As long as the "=" operator being declared in the package declaration isn't used elsewhere in the package body you could use a context clause before the package body:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164."=";
```

and

```
return l = r;
```

Also the equality operator is rigidly defined.

IEEE Std 1076-1993, 7.2.2 Relational operators, Para 4:

> ... Two scalar values of the same type are equal if and only if the values are the same.

So, no equality returns FALSE just because they are meta values.  It's illegal to redefine what 'equal' means.

And ya, I know of one tool that will let you analyze this or something close, but it'll fail when using the operator.  Even if it worked it would not be portable (while still being illegal, immoral and likely bad for the waistline).

This code crashes in ghdl, it was an attempt to avoid using the -fexplicit flag artificially changing the precedence of overloaded operators, which isn't -2008 standard compliant:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.to_x01;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.is_x;

package std_logic_warning is
  function "="(l, r : std_logic) return boolean;
end package;

package body std_logic_warning is

    use ieee.std_logic_1164."=";

    function "="(l, r : std_logic) return boolean is
    begin
    if is_x(l) or is_x(r) then
      report "std_logic_warning.""="": metavalue detected, returning FALSE"
        severity WARNING;
      return FALSE;
    end if;
    return l = r; -- std_logic_1164."="(l, r);
    end function;

end package body;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.std_ulogic;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic;
-- use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

use work.std_logic_warning.all;
entity warning_test is
end entity;

architecture foo of warning_test is
    signal a: std_logic;
    signal b: std_logic;
begin

UNLABELLED:
    process
    begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        a <= 'X';
        wait for 1 ns;
        b <= '1';
        wait for 1 ns;
        a <= '0';
        wait for 1 ns;
        b <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;

MONITOR:
    process (a,b)
    begin
        assert a = b 
            report "a = b " & "( " & std_logic'image(a)
                             & "=" & std_logic'image(b) & " )"
                severity NOTE;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

> ghdl -r warning_test
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:17:7:@0ms:(report warning):
>   std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:57:9:@0ms:(assertion note): a = b ( 'U'='U' )
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:17:7:@1ns:(report warning):
>   std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:57:9:@1ns:(assertion note): a = b ( 'X'='U' )
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:17:7:@2ns:(report warning):
>   std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:57:9:@2ns:(assertion note): a = b ( 'X'='1' )
>   ghdl: exec error

I'd suspect the issue has something to do with stack allocation, determined by trying concurrent assertions instead of the monitor process (which output more before crashing).

What it does show before bombing out is that `'U'='U'` is a valid equality comparison according to the LRM and your `"=" operator say it isn't.

You could note your equality operator `"="` is declared in the package declaration while the use clause is in effect in the package body.  There should be no IR2058 conflict noted by Jim in his answer. That use clause (in the package body) isn't visible to where your overload function is visible.

To use your declaration in the test bench the order of use clauses was carefully crafted:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.std_ulogic;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.std_logic;
-- use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

use work.std_logic_warning.all;
```

This also side steps the use of the Modelsim or ghdl overload rule evasion (-fexplicit as a command line argument in ghdl).

**Unfortunately this demonstrates how complex VHDL is more than anything else**

An acquaintance pointed out there was recursion in the function call so I proved that was the case by changing the function name (and changing the assertion condition expression).

> ghdl -a test.vhdl
>   ghdl -e warning_test
>   ghdl -r warning_test
>   test.vhdl:16:7:@0ms:(report warning): std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   test.vhdl:56:9:@0ms:(assertion note): a = b ( 'U'='U' )
>   test.vhdl:16:7:@1ns:(report warning): std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   test.vhdl:56:9:@1ns:(assertion note): a = b ( 'X'='U' )
>   test.vhdl:16:7:@2ns:(report warning): std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   test.vhdl:56:9:@2ns:(assertion note): a = b ( 'X'='1' )
>   test.vhdl:56:9:@3ns:(assertion note): a = b ( '0'='1' )

The recursion revolves around the function return expression "=".

commenting out the use clause in the package body yields:

```
-- use ieee.std_logic_1164."=";
```

> ghdl -a test.vhdl
>   test.vhdl:20:14: no function declarations for operator "="
>   ghdl: compilation error

Which says the use clause is necessary, and that's expected:

IEEE Std 1076-1993 Section 3 Types, Para 2:

> ...The set of operations of a type includes the explicitly declared
>   subprograms that have a parameter or result of the type. The remaining
>   operations of a type are the basic operations and the predefined
>   operators (see 7.2). These operations are each implicitly declared for
>   a given type declaration immediately after the type declaration and
>   before the next explicit declaration, if any.

So is the issue overload resolution?   (No it's visibility).

10.5 The context of overload resolution:

> Overloading is defined for names, subprograms, and enumeration
>   literals.
>
> For overloaded entities, overload resolution determines the actual
>   meaning that an occurrence of an identifier or a character literal has
>   whenever the visibility rules have determined that more than one
>   meaning is acceptable at the place of this occurrence; overload
>   resolution likewise determines the actual meaning of an occurrence of
>   an operator or basic operation (see the introduction to Section 3).

We've first got to determine if both declarations of the function "=" are visible.

10.4 Use clauses, para 3:

> Each selected name in a use clause identifies one or more declarations
>   that will potentially become directly visible. If the suffix of the
>   selected name is a simple name, character literal, or operator symbol,
>   then the selected name identifies only the declaration(s) of that
>   simple name, character literal, or operator symbol contained within
>   the package or library denoted by the prefix of the selected name.

10.4 Use clauses, para 4:

> For each use clause, there is a certain region of text called the
>   scope of the use clause. This region starts immediately after the use
>   clause. If a use clause is a declarative item of some declarative
>   region, the scope of the clause extends to the end of the declarative
>   region. If a use clause occurs within the context clause of a design
>   unit, the scope of the use clause extends to the end of the
>   declarative region associated with the design unit. The scope of a use
>   clause may additionally extend into a configuration declaration(see
>   10.2 ).

And about here we note that this use clause is within the package body, and it's effect doesn't extend anywhere else.  We also know that the declared function (originally also "=" is directly visible (i.e. not by selection) from the package declaration.

10.4 Use clauses, para 5:

> In order to determine which declarations are made directly visible at
>   a given place by use clauses, consider the set of declarations
>   identified by all use clauses whose scopes enclose this place. Any
>   declaration in this set is a potentially visible declaration. A
>   potentially visible declaration is actually made directly visible
>   except in the following two cases:
>
> > a. A potentially visible declaration is not made directly visible if
> >     the place considered is within the immediate scope of a homograph of
> >     the declaration.
> >
> > b. Potentially visible declarations that have the same designator are
> >     not made directly visible unless each of them is either an enumeration
> >     literal specification or the declaration of a subprogram (either by a
> >     subprogram declaration or by an implicit declaration).

And There is a homograph, the function declaration in the package declaration.

From Appendix B Glossary:

**B.117 homograph**: A reflexive property of two declarations. Each of two declarations is said to be a homograph of the other if both declarations have the same identifier and overloading is allowed for at most one of the two. If overloading is allowed for both declarations, then each of the two is a homograph of the other if they have the same identifier, operator symbol, or character literal, as well as the same parameter and result type profile.(§ 1.3.1 , § 10.3 )

**B.119 immediate scope**: A property of a declaration with respect to the declarative region within which the declaration immediately occurs. The immediate scope of the declaration extends from the beginning of the declaration to the end of the declarative region. (§ 10.2 )

So the issue revolves around immediate scope in 10.4, a. And b tells us that if both are subprogram declarations they are both visible inside the subprogram body.

And we get down to the NOTES:

> 1--These rules guarantee that a declaration that is made directly
>   visible by a use clause cannot hide an otherwise directly visible
>   declaration.

The use clause declaration that would become potentially visible is with in the immediate scope of the subprogram declaration found in the package declaration.

And if it weren't:

10.5 The context of overload resolution, para 3:

> At such a place, all visible declarations are considered. The
>   occurrence is only legal if there is exactly one interpretation of
>   each constituent of the innermost complete context; a complete context
>   is either a declaration, a specification, or a statement.

Not being legal is synonymous with error. We'd have gotten an error.

So the moral here is that VHDL can be complex especially when you're trying to game it. And what I was trying to do resulted in legal code that didn't do what was intended, and didn't generate and error until out of stack space at run time, a catch-22.

The displayed code can be made to function with the following change:

1. Remove the use clause in the package body:

   -- use ieee.std_logic_1164."=";
2. Restore EquipDev's return statement:

   ```
   return l = r; -- std_logic_1164."="(l, r);
   ```

becomes

```
    return std_logic_1164."="(l, r);
```

again.  (Undoing my error).

This gives:

> ghdl -a std_logic_warning.vhdl
>   ghdl -e warning_test
>   ghdl -r warning_test
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:17:7:@0ms:(report warning): std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:58:9:@0ms:(assertion note): a = b ( 'U'='U' )
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:17:7:@1ns:(report warning): std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:58:9:@1ns:(assertion note): a = b ( 'X'='U' )
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:17:7:@2ns:(report warning): std_logic_warning."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:58:9:@2ns:(assertion note): a = b ( 'X'='1' )
>   std_logic_warning.vhdl:58:9:@3ns:(assertion note): a = b ( '0'='1' )

Which appears to be the correct result, because when `b` is assigned to `'0'` at 4 ns the assertion test won't trigger for either the function or monitor process.

**Recap**

Is it possible to replace the relational operator "=" for std_logic?

Yes, But it may not be practical.  Notice that there are use clauses for all the package std_logic_1164 names used except "=".  In -2008 you can declare contexts where you could construct such a context clause once and invoke it.  Or otherwise you could fill the package declaration with use clauses.

And the entire point of this exercise was to show that the adopted definition of "=" wasn't valid for meta values and is not standard compliant.   (The 7.2.2 para 4 quote above).

And as Jim points out assertion test monitors can take the place of any usefulness redefining "=" may have.

Comment: Thanks; I have updated the suggestion to address your points.  Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks of the the additional update; I have remove the `std_logic_original` package and used `std_logic_1164` extended name for access instead.  Using `use ieee.std_logic_1164."=";` made ModelSim crash, thus not that approach.

Comment: I got ghdl to crash too.  I'd suspect that it has to do with having both an eligible function and an implicitly defined one, they might vary in post processing or format. As Jim points out in his answer (indirectly) this stems from lack of standards adherence in implementation specifying which `"="`or other operator to use. And the point of analyzing, elaborating and simulating your function was to demonstrate that `'U'='U'` fits in the LRM definition of 'equal' and that you're function doesn't meet that definition.